# Within a module, are there any reserved class names?

Tags: ruby

**Within a module**, are there any reserved class names?

```
module MyLibrary
  class Class
  end

  class Object
  end

  class Banana < Object
  end
end
```

Ruby doesn't *seem* to be confused.

```
MyLibrary::Object.new.is_a?(::Object)
#=> true
MyLibrary::Class.new.class
#=> MyLibrary::Class
MyLibrary::Class.class
#=> Class
MyLibrary::Banana.new.is_a?(::Object)
#=> true
MyLibrary::Banana.new.is_a?(MyLibrary::Object)
#=> true
MyLibrary::Banana.ancestors
#=> [MyLibrary::Banana, MyLibrary::Object, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just the ruby reserved words like BEGIN and END. In fact they might be the only two.

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/keywords_rdoc.html

Just as an FYI Rails has a separate list of reserved words.

Comment: Why not link to the [official keyword documentation](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/keywords_rdoc.html)?